# Is there a way I can track the questions I asked?

Tags: support

How can I track all the questions I have previously asked? (This is a common feature on other forums.)

Comment: Your profile has all your posts on it if that's what you mean. Also we're a Q&A site not a forum which is a big difference on how our content.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on your profile (https://music.stackexchange.com/users/30360/jar?tab=profile) you can see your top questions:

[image]

But if you post a lot, not all of them are going to show there; only your top posts. To see all of your posts, click on **Activity** on the top left of your profile:

[image]

And you'll see another screen, with some of your questions and answers:

[image]

By clicking on the **Questions** or **Answers**, you'll see all of your questions or answers respectively.